# Running Mongodb javascript in Mongo 3.2

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

We are upgrading to MongoDB 3.2. Earlier for running mongodb javascript we used eval function : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/

Since the method is deprecated in java driver 3.0, I could not find any similar option to execute javascript. We used below code with earlier mongodb driver and looking something similar to this.

```
final DBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
command.put("eval", <JavaScript_to_execute>);
CommandResult result = mongoDB.command(command);
```

Thanks

Amandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mongo added depreciated warning - there is no plan when it will be switched  off.

As you have some custom function there - it could be legit to check if it was implemented or could be implemented in the future to avoid clash..

see [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17453)